# Dump a string or a (string, integer) tuple in pig

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop2

I have a simple pig script, I was able to read the data and dump the data. However, I failed to dump a string or a (string, int) tuple. Just wondering what am I missing here? Thanks a lot!

---

```
dataset = LOAD '/Users/me/input' USING PigStorage() AS (id:chararray,data:chararray);

dataset_GROUP = GROUP dataset ALL;
dataset_COUNT = FOREACH dataset_GROUP GENERATE COUNT(dataset);

DUMP "record_count = ";                 <-- this does not work
DUMP dataset_COUNT;                     <-- this works 
DUMP "record_count = ", dataset_COUNT;  <-- this does not work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use **`CONCAT()`** function of Apache Pig to concat your string to the result as follows:

```
dataset = LOAD '/Users/me/input' USING PigStorage() AS (id:chararray,data:chararray);

dataset_GROUP = GROUP dataset ALL;
dataset_COUNT = FOREACH dataset_GROUP GENERATE CONCAT('record_count = ', COUNT(dataset));

DUMP dataset_COUNT;
```

For more details on Concat() of **Apache Pig 0.13.0** you can check [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#concat)

If you are using older Pig version, then you can write your **User Defined Function (UDF)** which will do the concatination operation and return the result. For more details refer [Pig Documentation on UDF](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/udf.html)